# How to create a script that would execute a command at double-click?

Tags: command-line, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a script that opens a terminals and execute commands in them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-to-make-a-script-that-opens-a-terminals-and-execute-commands-in-them)

I want to know how to create a script that I could put on the desktop and execute on double-click so as to run a command in terminal.

I know how to make the script executable but do not know what text it should have.

For example, my command could be `/etc/init.d/ccpd status`.

Creating an executable script like this

```
 #!/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

does nothing, while in terminal it is like this:

```
~$ /etc/init.d/ccpd status
/usr/sbin/ccpd: 2568 2564
```

I am aware that my question looks similar to this [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/46627/47206). But, trying to use that 10-up-voted definitive [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46630/47206), it doesn't give me enough information so as to do it right.

What to do - according to that answer? Creating a script like this

```
 #!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e [/etc/init.d/ccpd status]
```

gives error

[image]

How to modify the script to make it work?

---

**Considering the closing as duplicate:** i voted to close but now looking closer at the answers I see that this question clearly puts something that the other one just implies. I mean, one has to know the answer to this one (how to create the simplest script) just to understand the answers to the other. This maybe means it is not duplicate: or maybe a new answer/edit is needed in the other one in case this was closed.