# Command to see media file info in terminal?

Tags: command-line, multimedia, metadata

I need a command to quickly see in terminal essential information about an audio or video file.

(Then I'll consider adding that to Thunar's custom actions, etc.)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/obtain-avi-file-info-from-command-line

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`avprobe` from the package `libav-tools` is pretty good.

Sample output `avprobe somefile.mp4`

```
avprobe version 0.8.4-4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:33 with gcc 4.6.3
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'somefile.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-08-10 15:01:14
  Duration: 00:01:02.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 682 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1904x1040 [PAR 1:1 DAR 119:65], 680 kb/s, 19.18 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn, 40 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-08-10 15:01:14
```

To add to Thunar custom action, in relation to what was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/249846/47206), the analog formula to add would be:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "avprobe %f"
```

Comment: For those on `ffmpeg` still, `ffprobe` does the same.

Comment: Didn't work for me to find out remote video info under proxy environment. This one worked: `mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 http://example.com/myvideo.mkv`

Answer (score 57):

I use `mediainfo` to get all properties of media files ( audio and video files )

```
root@server:Videos::08:47 PM# mediainfo Vazquez.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : Vazquez.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 103 MiB
Duration                                 : 3mn 52s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 3 730 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-11-10 07:30:57
Tagged date                              : UTC 2011-11-10 07:30:57
gsst                                     : 0
gstd                                     : 232083
gssd                                     : B7AA66E45HH1322313268839354
gshh                                     : o-o.preferred.bhartibb-blr1.v12.lscache7.c.youtube.com

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=24
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 3mn 52s
Bit rate                                 : 3 576 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 5 947 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.072
Stream size                              : 98.9 MiB (96%)
Tagged date                              : UTC 2011-11-10 07:30:58

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 3mn 52s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 152 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 188 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.20 MiB (4%)
Title                                    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-11-10 07:30:58
Tagged date                              : UTC 2011-11-10 07:30:58
```

[`mediainfo`](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) is now in Ubuntu repositories and can be installed by running

```
sudo apt install mediainfo
```

Previously it was necessary to use [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~shiki/+archive/ubuntu/mediainfo) but this has no packages for current Ubuntu versions.

Comment: You don't need a PPA any more.

Comment: also, if you pass `.` as a file name then *mediainfo* will recursively list all files in the current folder.

Comment: `exiftool` has a ton more info, including geolocation. See also: https://superuser.com/a/1370421/425838, and [the other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/249966/327339). Pipe to grep to quickly jump to the `GPS` lines and see the geo-tagging/geo-location of the photo as well: `exiftool myphoto.jpg | grep GPS`.

Answer (score 28):

## exiftool

This might be a surprise, but [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) from libimage-exiftool-perl has this capability as well.

It supports showing info from [a lot of media file formats](https://exiftool.org/#supported), and can write metadata too for some of these formats.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

**Example output for an audio file:**

```
# exiftool The\ Police\ -\ Live\!\ Disc\ 2\ -\ Atlanta\ -\ 01.\ Synchronicity\ I.mp3 
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.13
File Name                       : The Police - Live! Disc 2 - Atlanta - 01. Synchronicity I.mp3
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 3.9 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2012:03:23 19:44:23+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2012:12:26 11:44:38+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2012:03:23 19:44:23+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-------
File Type                       : MP3
MIME Type                       : audio/mpeg
MPEG Audio Version              : 1
Audio Layer                     : 3
Sample Rate                     : 44100
Channel Mode                    : Joint Stereo
MS Stereo                       : On
Intensity Stereo                : Off
Copyright Flag                  : False
Original Media                  : True
Emphasis                        : None
VBR Frames                      : 6660
VBR Bytes                       : 4044318
VBR Scale                       : 57
Encoder                         : LAME3.96
Lame VBR Quality                : 4
Lame Quality                    : 3
Lame Method                     : VBR (old/rh)
Lame Low Pass Filter            : 18 kHz
Lame Bitrate                    : 32 kbps
Lame Stereo Mode                : Joint Stereo
Track                           : 1/15
Disc                            : 2/2
Artist                          : The Police
Title                           : Synchronicity I
Album                           : Live!
Year                            : 2003
Genre                           : Rock
Comment                         : Atlanta
Discid                          : c611270f
ID3 Size                        : 128
Audio Bitrate                   : 186 kbps
Date/Time Original              : 2003
Duration                        : 0:02:53 (approx)
```

Comment: very nice. can be used for images too. (for avi files: no audio bitrate. but a lot of other info)

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/a/1370421/425838. Pipe to grep to quickly jump to the `GPS` lines and see the geo-tagging/geo-location of the photo as well: `exiftool myphoto.jpg | grep GPS`.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what you consider *essential*, you might want to use the [`file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/file.1.html) utility for this, which gives general information on *any* file. Its primary purpose is to tell you what *type* of file you have, but it may provide the level of detail you need.

```
$ file '01 - Nina Simone - Mood Indigo.mp3'
01 - Nina Simone - Mood Indigo.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```

However, if you need to know the *contents* of tags--title, artists, etc.--`file` will not tell you that.

Comment: And you do not have to install extra software for this.

Answer (score 3):

There are also the following for audio files, although may not compete well with **exiftool**:

```
id3v2 -l <filename>
soxi <filename>
```

Also **soxi** supports video files as well.

The [id3v2 [image]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/id3v2) and [sox [image]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sox) packages (which can be installed by clicking these links) provide those commands. They can also be installed in the *Software Center*, or by running:

```
sudo apt-get install sox
sudo apt-get install id3v2
```

**An example**: `id3v2 -l 'Beatles - Here Comes The Sun.mp3'` output:

```
id3v1 tag info for Beatles - Here Comes The Sun.mp3:
Title  : Here Comes The Sun              Artist: Beatles                       
Album  : Abbey Road                      Year: 1969, Genre: Pop (13)
Comment:                                 Track: 7
id3v2 tag info for Beatles - Here Comes The Sun.mp3:
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): Here Comes The Sun
TYER (Year): 1969
TPUB (Publisher): Capitol
TCON (Content type): Pop (13)
TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Abbey Road
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
TRCK (Track number/Position in set): 7
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
TPE2 (Band/orchestra/accompaniment): The Beatles
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
PRIV (Private frame):  (unimplemented)
TCOM (Composer): George Harrison
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Beatles
```

Comment: id3v2 -l merely displays ID3 tags, soxi supports a limited number of audio and video formats.

Comment: when i run `soxi some.mp3` i get `no handler for file extension mp3`. the same for avi. `soxi supports a limited number of audio and video formats`: THAT limited, or is there something more to do beside installing them?

Comment: Other answers give exemplary output. Would be nice to see this here, too.

Answer (score 3):

I knew about this command: `avconv -i <filename>`

For myfile.flv: `avconv -i myfile.flv`

My idea was to add that command to [Thunar's custom actions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThunarCustomActions) and just run it from context menu no matter the extension. But it had to be run in terminal, so I took a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46630/47206). (To open the terminal and keep it open, I created a new profile in gnome-terminal (Edit/Profiles) called "new1", and under Profile preferences/"Title and command" set it "When command exits" to "Hold the terminal open".)

In the end (by trial and error) I came up with this:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "avconv -i %f"
```

which works put in Thunar's custom actions - and should work for any media file.

Comment: `avprobe` and `avconv` use the same underlying library, and give you the same results, but `avconv` is the encoder so with this command you also get an error at the end `At least one output file must be specified`.

Comment: Anyone interested may want to see the [chat discussion here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7338/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-cipricus). Topics include differences between different terminal apps, and different programs giving more or less desirable output depending on file type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu Xfce with Thunar then this will work in the custom actions:

xfce4-terminal --hold -e "avprobe %f"