# Get information about a video from command-line tool

Tags: command-line, multimedia, metadata

How can I get information about a video with a command-line tool? (e.g. video duration, audio codec, bitrate etc)

Comment: Yes, I said that in the answer and I flagged the question as it.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I didn't see that question even tough I searched for something similar in the portal before. Sorry! :P

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have several commands to get that information:

> `avprobe` from the package `libav-tools` is pretty good.
>
> Sample output `avprobe somefile.mp4`
>
> ```
> avprobe version 0.8.4-4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c)
> 2007-2012 the Libav developers   built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:33 with
> gcc 4.6.3 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'somefile.mp4':  
> Metadata:
>     major_brand     : avc1
>     minor_version   : 0
>     compatible_brands: isomavc1
>     creation_time   : 2012-08-10 15:01:14   Duration: 00:01:02.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 682 kb/s
>     Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1904x1040 [PAR 1:1 DAR 119:65], 680 kb/s, 19.18 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn, 40 tbc
>     Metadata:
>     creation_time   : 2012-08-10 15:01:14
> ```
>
> To add to Thunar custom action, in relation to what was suggested
>   here, the analog formula to add would be:
>
> ```
> gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "avprobe %f"
> ```

Source: [Command to see media file info in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249828/command-to-see-media-file-info-in-terminal) (then, duplicated).

And also you have:

> You can use MPlayer to get that information.
>
> ```
> $ mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 foo.avi
> ```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/55780/linux-command-line-tool-to-get-bitrate-of-divx-xvid

Comment: On MacOSX /w Homebrew: `brew install libav` will get you the avprobe binary.

Comment: On a side note, why would avprobe send its output to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: It should be noted that `mpv`/`libav` (from which `avprobe` is) is a fork of `mplayer`/`ffmpeg`, for purposes of a cleaner rewrite, with both the good (cleanup) and the bad (missing features). Choose your poison. :)

Answer (score 18):

There are several ways to achieve this. Here are three methods, using three different utilities.

## Using exiftool

1. Install `libimage-exiftool-perl` using the command `sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl`.
2. Run `exiftool /path/to/file`
3. The output you get is similar to this:

   ```
   ExifTool Version Number         : 9.04
   File Name                       : filename.avi
   Directory                       : Path/To/File
   File Size                       : ### MB
   File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:04:14 10:46:51+04:00
   File Access Date/Time           : 2013:05:19 09:21:08+04:00
   File Permissions                : rwxrwxr--
   File Type                       : AVI
   MIME Type                       : video/x-msvideo
   Frame Rate                      : 25
   Max Data Rate                   : 0 kB/s
   Frame Count                     : 105154
   Stream Count                    : 2
   Stream Type                     : Video
   Video Codec                     : xvid
   Video Frame Rate                : 25
   Video Frame Count               : 105154
   Quality                         : 10000
   Sample Size                     : Variable
   Image Width                     : 640
   Image Height                    : 360
   Planes                          : 1
   Bit Depth                       : 12
   Compression                     : XVID
   Image Length                    : 1382400
   Pixels Per Meter X              : 0
   Pixels Per Meter Y              : 0
   Num Colors                      : Use BitDepth
   Num Important Colors            : All
   Audio Codec                     : 
   Audio Sample Rate               : 41.67
   Audio Sample Count              : 175252
   Encoding                        : MP3
   Num Channels                    : 2
   Sample Rate                     : 48000
   Avg Bytes Per Sec               : 16000
   Bits Per Sample                 : 0
   Stream Name                     : filename.audio
   Duration                        : 1:10:06
   Image Size                      : 640x360
   ```

<sub>Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474839&p=2851338#post2851338</sub>

---

## Using ffmpeg

1. Install `ffmpeg` using the command `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`.
2. Run `ffmpeg -i /path/to/file`
3. The output you get is similar to this:

   ```
   Input #0, avi, from 'Path/To/File':
     Duration: 01:10:06.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1172 kb/s
       Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
       Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
       Metadata:
          title           : filename.audio
   ```

<sub>Source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2207/get-video-information-with-ffmpeg</sub>

---

## Using mplayer

1. Install `mplayer` using the command `sudo apt-get install mplayer`.
2. Run `mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 /path/to/file`
3. The output you get is similar to this:

   ```
   Playing Path/To/File.
   libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)
   Mismatching header version 53.19.0
   AVI file format detected.
   ID_VIDEO_ID=0
   [aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
   ID_AUDIO_ID=1
   [aviheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
   VIDEO:  [XVID]  640x360  12bpp  25.000 fps  1031.9 kbps (126.0 kbyte/s)
   Load subtitles in Path/To/File
   ID_FILENAME=Path/To/File
   ID_DEMUXER=avi
   ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=XVID
   ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=1031880
   ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=640
   ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=360
   ID_VIDEO_FPS=25.000
   ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
   ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=85
   ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=127992
   ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
   ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
   ID_START_TIME=0.00
   ID_LENGTH=4206.16
   ID_SEEKABLE=1
   ID_CHAPTERS=0
   ==========================================================================
   Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
   libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)
   Mismatching header version 53.32.2
   Unsupported PixelFormat 61
   Unsupported PixelFormat 53
   Unsupported PixelFormat 81
   Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
   ==========================================================================
   ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffodivx
   ==========================================================================
   Requested audio codec family [mpg123] (afm=mpg123) not available.
   Enable it at compilation.
   Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
   AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 128.0 kbit/4.17% (ratio: 16000->384000)
   ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=128000
   ID_AUDIO_RATE=48000
   ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
   Selected audio codec: [ffmp3float] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG layer-3 audio)
   ==========================================================================
   AO: [null] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
   ID_AUDIO_CODEC=ffmp3float
   Starting playback...


   Exiting... (End of file)
   ID_EXIT=EOF
   ```

<sub>Source: https://superuser.com/a/55802</sub>

Comment: exiftool is good for simple the output format, for example I wanted to see video codecs of my AVI files, and highlight those in "divx", and obtained with this script:
exiftool * | grep "Video Codec\|File Name" | grep --color -E '^|divx'