# Total video time in a Directory

Tags: command-line, scripts, video

Is there a script(bash, python etc.) that outputs the total duration time of all video files in a Directory(recursively) ?

For e.g on executing the following :

```
script mypath
```

it gives `x minutes/hours` .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First install `mediainfo` with:

```
sudo apt-get install mediainfo
```

You can now use the following oneliner to get the total video time of a directory:

```
find . -type f -exec mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" "{}" \; 2>/dev/null | awk '{s+=$1/1000} END {h=s/3600; s=s%3600; printf "%.2d:%.2d\n", int(h), int(s/60)}'
```

The `find` command will call `mediainfo` for every files recursively and get the video duration in ms.

Then the `awk` part will sum those values and return the total time in the `HH:MM` format.

---

**Update**: `avprobe` is indeed faster than `mediainfo` (thanks @[souravc](https://askubuntu.com/users/127327/souravc))

For better results please use the command below instead (you'll need to `sudo apt-get install libav-tools` first)

```
find . -type f -exec avprobe -v quiet -show_format_entry duration "{}" \; | awk '{s+=$1} END {h=s/3600; s=s%3600; printf "%.2d:%.2d\n", int(h), int(s/60)}'
```

Comment: No.It works for small directory but gives some 2hours for large directory. Before installing gawk, I was getting a error like : "strftime : function not defined in awk ". @SylvainPineau may be the hours overflow ?(guessing)

Comment: @AtulGangwar Please try my updated version

Comment: @SylvainPineau Thanks. I added this as a function in my ~/.bashrc and passed the path as argument :)

Comment: @SylvainPineau I am getting `E: File read error` while executing in a directory (have other files apart from video files). IMHO `mediainfo` is comparatively slow than `avprobe`. It is taking time more than twice than that of `avprobe`.

Comment: @souravc I've updated my answer with `avprobe` as it's indeed much faster than mediainfo (I've also fixed the first version read error msg)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following script to know **Total Duration of all video files in a Directory recursively**. I have used [`avprobe`](https://askubuntu.com/a/249843/127327) in the following script which comes with `libav-tools`

Install `libav-tools` as,

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

**Save the script** as `get_video_duration.sh`(say). Give it execution permission from a terminal as

```
chmod u+x get_video_duration.sh
```

**How to run the script**

To know total video duration of the directory `/full/path/to/videodir`, run with argument as

```
./get_video_duration.sh /full/path/to/videodir
```

Or to know total video duration of current directory run without any argument as

```
./get_video_duration.sh .
```

**For Recursion** append `-R` or `-r` or `-recursive` or `--recursive` after the directory path. For example to know total video duration of the directory `/full/path/to/videodir` recursively (also search all folders inside `/full/path/to/videodir`)

```
./get_video_duration.sh /full/path/to/videodir -R
```

**The script is as following:**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mysep="======================================================================================"
mysmallsep="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
if [ -n "$1" ];then
    mypath="$1"
else
    mypath="$(pwd)"
fi
declare -a my_path_array
get_duration(){
    /usr/bin/avprobe "$1" 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk -F[:,] '{print int($2*3600+$3*60+$4)}'
}
print_duration(){
    awk -v var="$1" 'BEGIN {print int(var/3600)"Hr "int((var%3600)/60)"Min "int(var%60)"Sec "}'
}
execute_it_now(){
    echo -e "Video File\t\tVideo Duration"
    echo $mysep
    echo "$1"
    echo $mysmallsep
    j=0
    for i in "$1"/{*.mp4,*.mkv,*.avi,*.flv} ## Put the existing video file extension you have
    do
        if [[ "$(get_duration "$i")" -ne "0" ]];then
            echo -e "$(basename "$i")\t$(tput setaf 2)$(print_duration $(get_duration "$i"))$(tput sgr0)"
        fi
        let j=j+$(get_duration "$i") 2>/dev/null
    done
    echo $mysep
    echo "Total Duration $(tput setaf 1)$(print_duration $j)$(tput sgr0)"
}
execute_these_now(){
    for i in "$1"/{*.mp4,*.mkv,*.avi,*.flv} ## Put the existing video file extension you have
    do
        if [[ "$(get_duration "$i")" -ne "0" ]];then
            echo -e "$(basename "$i")\t$(tput setaf 2)$(print_duration $(get_duration "$i"))$(tput sgr0)"
        fi
    done
}
add_these_now(){
    j=0;
    for i in "$1"/{*.mp4,*.mkv,*.avi,*.flv} ## Put the existing video file extension you have
    do
        let j=j+$(get_duration "$i") 2>/dev/null
    done
    echo $j
}
case "$2" in
        -R|-r|-recursive|--recursive) 
        tmp=$(find $mypath -type d | xargs)
        my_path_array=( $tmp )
        echo -e "Video File\t\tVideo Duration"
        echo $mysep
        k=0;
        for indx in $(seq ${#my_path_array[@]})
    do
            echo ${my_path_array[$(($indx-1))]}
            echo $mysmallsep
            execute_these_now ${my_path_array[$(($indx-1))]}
            let k=k+$(add_these_now ${my_path_array[$(($indx-1))]})
    done
        echo $mysep
        echo "Total Duration $(tput setaf 1)$(print_duration $k)$(tput sgr0)"
           ;;
        *) 
            execute_it_now $mypath
           ;;
esac
```

**Screen shot of execution of the script**

[image]

***Note:** As I don't have any `.mkv` or `.avi` file in my home directory last two lines in the screen shot appeared with duration  0Hr 0Min 0Sec*

Comment: will this work if the files do not have extensions(but are still video files)?

Comment: just use `for i in $mypath/*` in stead of `for i in $mypath/{*.mp4,*.mkv,*.avi}`

Comment: Nice script. It lists all files with duration and total duration only in the current directory but doesn't go recursive. Also, when i use `for i in $mypath/*`  it lists other files with 0 duration. So, the application is different from SylvainPineau's answer but nonetheless useful :)

Comment: May be add an option like "-R" to handle both cases, since only searching current dir can be useful too .

Comment: @AtulGangwar just see the revised code. hope this will serve your purpose. :)

Comment: Seems to work great provided that the folder names do not contain spaces....

Comment: Hello, newer ubuntu versions switched to `ffprobe` (package `ffmpeg`) instead of `avprobe`. Just switching the name in the script suffice (but attenction to the problem of spaces in the directory names.. can this be sorted?)