# How to Sort/Search video files on the basis of properties?

Tags: nautilus, video, files, file-properties, nautilus-script

This is a unique situation

I've more than 500 Movies in a partition. what I wanted to do is search movie files on the basis of Property ***Video Dimension***, so that I could delete anything which is below 720p HD, to make space for other stuff.

Search option in nautilus can search by dates or file types but not properties. is there another application that i can use? or Command? or *Nautilus-Script*?

[image: Highlighting video dimension]

**UPDATE**

```
find . -name '*.mkv' -exec exiftool -fileName -imageSize {} \;
```

This command works as expected but i want this command to do a little bit more. i don't know how *ExifTool* works so i can't modify it

**can I add multiple file extensions in single command?**
most of the files are `mkv` but it includes `mp4` `flv`. a single command scanning all these video extensions could save a lot of work

[image]

(see how many sub folders are there)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249828/command-to-see-media-file-info-in-terminal with some combination of `find` and `grep`.

Comment: @muru i read that question, my beginners ubuntu mind could grasp what it could but it's still really unclear to me, can there be a **nautilus-script** for this? because i don' want to use other file managers

Comment: This might lead you in the right direction http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85949/show-video-files-with-its-size

Comment: @bart `exiftool` did work, but there are a few minor problems. i've updated the question accordingly, thanks for the help

Comment: As mentioned by @muru you will have to use a combination of tools and pipe the output between them, there is no easy solution as any attempt of rm on you file system can have catastrophic effect. Use "man find" to get all your files pipe that to "man exiftool" and you can drop the output to file with ">"

Comment: @bart i just want to add `mp4` and `mkv` extensions in single command? i tried what i could, i'm still trying, can you help me with that?

Comment: eg find ./Videos -type f -name "\*.mp4" -o -name "\*.mkv"   just modify the path to where your videos are

Comment: @muru oh! i'm sorry, i did not know that, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable extended and recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
```

Then:

```
exiftool -q -p '$FileName $ImageSize' **/+(*.mp4|*.mkv|*.flv)
```

`**` will recurse into subdirectories. The extended glob `+(*.mp4|...)` will match at least one of the patterns inside the `()`.

You can use grep to process the output and generate a list of files not `1920x1080`:

```
exiftool -q -p '$Directory/$FileName $ImageSize' **/+(*.mp4|*.mkv|*.flv) |
  grep -v ' 1920x1080$'
```

Note the change here: I'm using `$Directory/$FileName $Imagesize`. We need the path to the file, not just the filename, so `$Directory/$Filename`. And 
Here we check if each line doesn't end with `1920x1080` (`$` is the end of line, `-v` in grep inverts the match). **Verify the output**.

Now we can delete these files:

```
exiftool -q -p '$Directory/$FileName $ImageSize' **/+(*.mp4|*.mkv|*.flv) |
  grep -v ' 1920x1080$' | sed 's: [^ ]*$::' |
  xargs -d '\n' rm
```

`sed 's: [^ ]*$::'` removes everything from the last  until the end of the line, so the `AxB` resolution from the output of `exiftool` is removed, keeping only the filename. Then `xargs rm` takes each line as a filename and runs `rm` with them as argument.

Disable the globbing options when done:

```
shopt -u globstar globstar
```

To exclude multiple resolutions, use an OR in `grep`:

```
grep -Ev ' (1920x1080|1920x820|1280x544)$'
```

Here is a command with all the widely used video formats

```
exiftool -q -p '$Directory/$FileName $ImageSize' **/+(*.mp4|*.mkv|*.flv|*.avi|*.webm|*.vob|*.mov|*.wmv|*.amv|*.m4p|*.m4v|*.mpeg|*.mpv|*.m4v|*.3gp)
```

Here is a command excluding (almost) all the HD Video formats

```
grep -Ev ' (1920x1080|1920x1040|1920x1068|1906x952|1916x808|1920x808|1920x804|1916x812|1600x864|1436x1080|1920x820|1280x544|1920x800|1920x802|1920x816|1856x1080|1920x1072|1920x1056|1280x720|1280x536|1280x560|1280x538|1280x528|1216x544|1280x534|1280x532|1281x534|1278x714|1280x718|1280x688|1278x682|1280x690|1280x694|1280x660|1282x692|1280x692|1285x696|1278x544|1280x696|1279x718|1280x546|1281x546|960x720|1324x552|1305x552|1308x552|1536x640)$'
```

Comment: Nice one, so simple :)

Comment: Can we exclude multiple resolutions too? For eg `1920x816`, `1920x820`, `1280x544`  , I'm talking about all the resolutions that can be defined as HD or above. I want to keep those (i should probably stop, I'm asking for more and more)

Comment: just tried it and it worked (couldn't try it before), "it worked" is an oversimplification, it worked like charm. if you could update the answer with code to exclude at least **two resolutions** i can add all the others on my own. if you can't, that's fine too, i can live with this! linux is amazing, let me upvote that answer

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh see update.