# From Terminal-1, Create new terminal, execute command (e.g: start JBoss), come back to Terminal-1

Tags: gnome-terminal

As Stated in the title, I want to start a new terminal from (say) Terminal-1. The new Terminal will execute a command (Say, start JBoss). And after starting JBoss, there will be JBoss log in Terminal-2, so i dont want to stay there as I have some other tasks to do. I want the control back to Terminal-1, so I can execute other commands. I am running script.

Example scenario:
Running a script where i need to:
(1) Install JBoss
(2) Start JBoss
(3) Deploy a code in jboss as.

NOTE: Creating a new Terminal is not a problem. I can follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the). The problem is to come back to the primary terminal for executing further command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do :

```
gnome-terminal -e jboss_command; exit;
```

That should close the new terminal as soon as the `jboss_command` finishes.

However, you almost certainly don't want that. There is no reason to open a new terminal. Just run your command in the background:

```
jboss_command &
```

If that creates output, run it like this:

```
jboss_command &>/dev/null &
```

The `&` at the end makes a command run in the background, allowing you to keep using the terminal. `&>/dev/null` redirects standard error and standard output to `/dev/null`, it basically discards any messages printed by the command. So, running your `jboss` command like this will enable you to keep working on the same terminal while the command is running.

Comment: "jboss_command &>/dev/null &"

worked perfectly for me.
Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

I like using 'screen' for this sort of work. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install screen` and use it like this:

- Open new screen (terminal) with `screen`
- Execute your command(s) in it
- Detach it (temporarily exit) with 'ctrl+a' release keys and then press only 'd'
- Optionally open another one and do some stuff there too, detach that one also
- When you want to come back type `screen -ls`
- And then reattach one you want with `screen -r screen_name`

`man screen` for more!

Comment: any alternatives to 'ctrl+a' ? I am thinking to run a script where i dont know how to use 'ctrl+a' unfortunately.