# Xubuntu 12.04: "Open In Terminal" doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, command-line, xubuntu, gnome-terminal

You may be wondering why I'm using an outdated version, that is because my network card doesn't work in `14.04`.

Anyways, I have set `chmod +x` (`even u+x`) to my `.sh` file, and when I double click, nothing happens. It just looks like it's loading something, but then nothing happens.

I also tried `"Open in terminal"` which doesn't work as well. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

My terminal works just fine, it's just these shortcuts that don't work.

Comment: You might wanna take a peak [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/46627/295286) , and as for your network card, I'm guessing you have broadcom, don't you ?

Comment: I have a Belkin N300. My LAN adapter shouldn't effect anything, right? Also that link works! Thanks. I am new to .sh scripts so, I am nooby to this stuff.

Comment: I have a **Silicon Integrated Systems SiS SiS900 PCI Fast** - but idk if that has to do with my wireless card not working.