# how to run this everytime after a reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

If I open a terminal and run this in the terminal: `source /home/deploy/script.sh`

It will execute `script.sh`

command below is what i wrote in script.sh

```
cd /var/www/applikasi-siao/iClockServer && thin -e production -p 2345 -P tmp/pids/thin.pid -l logs/thin/log start
```

this command above must run in the same terminal and the terminal should stay open.

I created `script.sh` so when i open terminal and type `source /home/deploy/script.sh` it will run

```
cd /var/www/applikasi-siao/iClockServer && thin -e production -p 2345 -P tmp/pids/thin.pid -l logs/thin/log start
```

I need all of this processes run automatically every reboot without manually opening a terminal and typing `source /home/deploy/script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Cron/Cronjobs will allow you to automate the task above to after every restart HOWEVER, it won't leave a terminal window open.

For info on Cron you can look at the CronHowto:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Also please mention what operating system you are using.

Crons are really quite interesting so I highly recommend reading into them but TLDR.

Open a terminal window.

Install Cron

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

After that has completed type

```
crontab -e
```

If the script requires administrative privileges use:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And then at the bottom of the file add the following with the path being to where that script is.

```
@reboot /home/username/start_application.sh
```

Comment: the terminal must remain open, im using ubuntu 14.04, gnome-schedule is already installed

Comment: this picture will show why i need it to remain open https://postimg.org/image/yi10jgvyd/

Comment: i tried to use starting application. I wrote command on startup :
[code]gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "/var/www/applikasi-siao/iClockServer/script.sh; exec bash"' [/code]

it started new terminal everyboot but it said thin command is not found, how can i change directory to /var/www/applikasi-siao/iClockServer before starting the thin - e bla bla bla

Comment: Not to pass the buck, but this question might help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the

Comment: I tried that, but it run as root, i need to run the script as user (my username= deploy)...so is there anything u could think of?