# Getting out of sudo -A

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, password, kde5

In the wake of `kdesudo`'s demise, I'm trying to replace it using `sudo -A` and a very simple helper script which calls `kdialog --password` based on an answer I got [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067139/23861).

I need this for use with `bash` scripts which may be invoked from a GUI where there is no terminal for normal command line i/o.

This has some nice options and works fine with one problem:

The dialog displayed by `kdialog` has `OK` and `Cancel` buttons.
If I change my mind and decide not to proceed, then selecting `Cancel`, pressing `Esc`, or just clicking on the X in the dialog window frame causes the dialog to be presented twice more (just like entering the wrong password would).

I haven't checked, but I bet it's logging three failed password attempts to my security log too when all I'm trying to do is quit the command.

Is there a way to tell it that I want to quit now?

Is this a bug in `kdialog` or `sudo`?

---

I'm running

```
kubuntu 18.04
KDE Frameworks 5.44.0
Qt 5.9.5 (built against 5.9.5)
The xcb windowing system
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I have looked at `pkexec` and don't want to deal with defining policies in XML. And it presents a huge, ugly dialog window that I really don't want to look at.

Also, I have scripts that need to run several elevated commands and if I don't run the whole script elevated (which I don't want to do), then I have to enter my password several times to do one task.

There's still a version of `kdesu` available, but it looks like that may go away too.

I also learned about using the `admin://` prefix for a file argument in a command, but some commands I need to elevate don't have any file arguments to apply it to.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your situation, but does using `pkexec` solve your problem?

Comment: @Jeremy - Not really, Its dialog is huge and ugly, I'd have to learn and debug XML to setup each app I need to run elevated, and, by default, I'd have to enter my password multiple times once for each elevated command in a script that is conceptually doing one thing. I haven't followed the debate, but from the outside, it looks like they've adopted the Firefox credo of "If it's not broke, fix it until it is."