# Auto start terminal based application in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I am using a terminal based application (you can only start running the application from the terminal),I was wondering if there is any possible ways I could auto-start that application when my computer is restarted?!

Comment: Lookup how to use "systemd targets". There are already many tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: One easy way is to use `@reboot` job within `crontab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create a desktop entry for that application and place it in ~/.config/autostart/

[How to create desktop entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)!

For terminal applications use `x-terminal-emulator -e program options`

in Exec key.

https://askubuntu.com/a/46640/894787

Comment: this how I start my application --> "cd MXT , sudo ./runMyapp.sh " so i basically  use the terminal everytime I want to start,  what I was asking is to auto-start it when I reboot my single board computer (Odroid XU4)