# Open a new gnome-terminal from a script, without weird side-effects

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I initially thought this would be a very simple thing to do:

write a script which opens several fresh gnome-terminal windows, runs a command in each of them, and leaves them open. The automated equivalent of doing CTRL+ALT+T several time, and running a single command in each of the opened windows.

However, looking at many answers here ([for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)), it seems like I am missing a simple answer or it does not exist.

Using the recommended

`gnome-terminal`
and its variations,
such as
`gnome-terminal --tab --title="test" --command="bash -c 'cd /etc; ls; $SHELL'"`

A new terminal window does open up, but it is a subshell, and .bashrc gets executed a second time. Thus some exports, and other commands fail or create doubled variables. (e.g. having `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` in .bashrc, the new terminal now has "history -a; history -a;" in $PROMPT_COMMAND).

Additionally, the command `gnome-terminal` seems to also inherit the working directory, and some (but not all) variables from the shell that launched it.

So is there a way to launch a fresh (i.e, in exactly the same state as if I pressed CTRL+ALT+T) gnome-terminal instance from the command line?

( `man gnome-terminal` and `gnome-terminal --help-all` do not mention such an option. )