# How to startup a bash in terminal emulator?

Tags: lubuntu, startup, lxterminal

I'm trying to start a script in LXDE. I've added it to startup and after restart it starts up but in the background not in a terminal window. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide release details, I'm assuming 18.04 given it's the only supported LXDE release for Lubuntu.  Running in the background is what most users want (they want the effects of their commands, not to see their script run)

Comment: Yes it is 18.04 LTS

Comment: There are 5 autorun scripts (.profile. .bash_profile, .bashrc etc) that run at various times which maybe what you want, but also may not be (eg. adding to one of them would result in it running first login (GUI or text login), or every time a terminal is opened so picking the right one for your needs would be important). They are what comes to mind for your question, but I'm unsure if its exactly what you want, refer https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a script that opens and runs in a terminal emulator.

[Here is a guide on how to run the script in a terminal by Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/a/46640/1187700)

Make another script like this that calls your script in a terminal and add it to startup.

```
x-terminal-emulator -e /home/user/hacky your-old-script optional arguments here
```